# Pulling from two arrays a non-matching object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I have two arrays. If an object in one array has no matching email attribute in the other, I want to build an array out of all those objects..

My attempts at attacking the dragon :

```
CardReferral.all.map(&:email) - CardSignup.all.map(&:email)
```

That almost does what I need! Unfortunately, it only supplies an email in an array. And I want the whole object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplified example:

```
a = [:x, :y, :z]
b = [:a, :y, :b]
a.select { |e| ! b.include? e }
=> [:x, :z]
```

So I guess in your case it goes something like:

```
CardReferral.all.select { |e| ! CardSignup.all.include? e.email }
```

Or, incorporating feedback :-) ...

```
t = CardSignup.all
CardReferral.all.reject { |e| t.include? e.email }
```

Comment: Would this call `CardSignup.all` in each iteration of the loop? Isn't that inefficient?

Answer (score 2):

```
t = CardSignup.all.map(&:email)
result = CardReferral.all.reject { |i| t.include? i.email }
```